# Writing onEdit trigger in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My colleague and I are teachers and do not have much background in programming. We have pieced together a script that creates a Google Calendar event from a Form fed spreadsheet; however, we cannot get the trigger to work.

Many have suggested moving away from time-based triggers because they can be unreliable, so we'd like to write our own trigger. After researching, it seems an `onEdit(e)` trigger would be best, but we can't get it to work conditionally. We'd like our script only to run if the approval column says "Yes" (column 13).

From what I've seen, it looks like we should probably be doing this completely differently (maybe with `getValue`), so I'm calling on everyone here for help. It seems like it should be so simple! FYI, `findRow` works and makes the calendar events, so we just need `findRow` to run if column 13 is "Yes."

Any help you can give is greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    var colToCheck = 13;
    if (colToCheck = "Yes");
    findRow;
};
```

Comment: Do you realize that a change in the spreadsheet from a form submit will not trigger an onEdit event?

Comment: For an equality test, you must use either a double or triple equal sign.  You are using a single equal sign: `if (colToCheck = "Yes")`  A single equal sign is an "Assignment Operator"  So what you are doing is assigning the value `"Yes"` to the variable `colToCheck`.  You are not testing for equality.  The best thing you can do as a beginner is read the troubleshooting guide.  [Link to Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what findRow() does.  But I think this is what you were trying to accomplish.

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var ss= e.source;
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var approval = sht.getRange(row,13).getValue();
  if (approval=="Yes")
  {
    findRow();
  }
}
```

By the way when I first started studying triggers, I wrote a routine that made a log entry every time I got a trigger and after exactly three days of one hour triggers I had 72 log entrees so I would say that they are very reliable.